# generating a random number within range 0 to n where n can be > RAND_MAX

Tags: c++, c

How can I generate a random number within range 0 to n where n can be > RAND_MAX in c,c++?

Thanks.

Comment: C and C++ give you different answers, which is it? For example, in C++ you could use boost's random library.

Comment: Check out: http://groups.google.com/group/sci.crypt.random-numbers/topics?lnk=rgr

Answer (score 8):

split the generation in two phases, then combine the resulting numbers.

Comment: I think the maths community at sci.crypt.random-number may have issues with the randomness of that.

Comment: Easy prediction. They have issues with the randomness of a single call, too. :)

Answer (score 5):

Random numbers is a very specialized subject that unless you are a maths junky is very easy to get wrong. So I would advice against building a random number from multiple sources you **should** use a good library.

I would first look at [boost::Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/random/index.html)

If that is not suffecient try of this group [sci.crypt.random-numbers](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.crypt.random-numbers/topics?lnk=rgr)
Ask the question there they should be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

suppose you want to generate a 64-bit random number, you could do this:

```
uint64_t n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    uint64_t x = generate_8bit_random_num();
    n = (n << (8 * i)) | x;
}
```

Of course you could do it 16/32 bits  at a time too, but this illustrates the concept.

How you generate that 8/16/32-bit random numbers is up to you. It could be as simple as `rand() & 0xff` or something better depending on how much you care about the randomness.

Comment: The question becomes how random are the bottom 8 bits of a value from rand()! I suspect that it is not as random as you think.

Comment: @Martin: more specifically, the question becomes how correlated the bottom 8 bits of rand() are between calls.

Comment: @Martin: that's why I wrote `generate_8bit_random_num();` instead of `rand() & 0xff` in my primary example. It is worth noting that gnu-glibc's `rand` function does have good randomness in the low bytes. They actually build the random number in stages and assemble the result.

Comment: @Evan. +1 now. You obviously know more than me (as you understand rand()). I just know leave it to pople that actually know the maths (Unfortunately most people think they do but don't). Like security randomness is a specialized field that is harder than it looks

Comment: Not a matter of knowing more :-). The man page has the following:

"The versions of rand() and srand() in the Linux C Library use the same random number generator as random(3) and srandom(3), so the  lower-order  bits should  be  as  random  as the higher-order bits.  However, on older rand() implementations, and on current implementations on different systems, the lower-order bits are much less random than the higher-order bits.  Do not use this function in applications intended to be portable when good randomness is needed.  (Use random(3) instead.)

Comment: RAND_MAX should be > (1<<14) everywhere which means you only need 5 calls.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C++, have you tried looking at a decent random number library, like [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/random/index.html). Otherwise you may have to combine multiple random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a uniform distribution (or any distribution for that manner) , you must take care that the statistical properties of the output are sufficient for your needs. If you can't use the output of a random number generator directly, you should be very careful trying to combine numbers to achieve your needs.

At a bare minimum you should make sure the distribution is appropriate. If you're looking for a uniform distribution of integers from 0 to M, and you have some uniform random number generator `g()` to produce outputs that are smaller than M, make sure you do **not** do one of the following:

- add k outputs of g() together until they're large enough (*the result is nonuniform*)
- take r = g() + (g() << 16), then compute r % M (*if the range of r is not an even multiple of M, it will weight certain values in the range slightly more than others; the shift-left itself is questionable unless g() outputs a range between 0 and a power of 2 minus 1*)

Beyond that, there is the potential for cross-correlation between terms of the sequence (random number generators are supposed to produce independent identically-distributed outputs).

Read The Art of Computer Programming vol. 2 (Knuth) and/or Numerical Recipes and ask questions until you feel confident.

Answer (score 1):

*If* your implementation has an integer type large enough to hold the result you need, it's generally easier to get a decent distribution by simply using a generator that produces the required range than to try to combine outputs from the smaller generator.

Of course, in most cases, you can just download code for something like the Mersenne Twister or (if you need a cryptographic quality generator) Blum-Blum-Shub, and forget about writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Do x random numbers (from 0 to RAND_MAX) and add them together, where

x = n % RAND_MAX

Comment: Do probabilities not matter at all?

Comment: I agree with @Sinan, this destroys the random distribution.

Comment: and yet a less descriptive version of this answer is top voted answer. Gotta love SO. It would only patrially destroy the distribution anyway, it'd only be significantly less random when x is very large. as x -> infinity you'd eventually see a completely non-random number, but I'd struggle to think of a situation where a random number much greater than 10 million would be required.

Comment: No, it actually becomes increasingly more random (more entropy) but the amount of entropy added for each increment of `x` tends to zero. However, statistics on infinite sets is a very complex topic, and 600 characters is completely insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

If you are OK with less granularity (higher chance of dupes), then something like (in pseudocode) `rand() * n / RAND_MAX` will work to spread the values across a larger range.  The catch is that in your real code you'll need to avoid overflow, either via casting rand() or n to a large-enough type (e.g. 64-bit int if RAND_MAX is 0xFFFFFFFF) to hold the multiplication result without overflow, or use a multiply-then-divide API (like GNU's MulDiv64 or Win32's [MulDiv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383718(VS.85).aspx)) which is optimized for this scenario.

If you want granuarity down to each integer, you can call rand() multiple times and append the results.  Another answer suggests calling rand() for each 8-bit/16-bit/32-bit chunk depending on size of RAND_MAX.

But, IMHO, the above ideas can rapidly get complicated, inaccurate, or both. Generating random numbers is a solved problem in other libraries, and it's probably much easier to borrow existing code (e.g. from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/random/index.html)) than try to roll your own.  [Open source random number generation algorithm in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190135/open-source-random-number-generation-algorithm-in-c) has answers with more links if you want something besides Boost.

[  EDIT: revising after having a busy day... meant to get back and clean up my quick answer this morning, but got pulled away and only getting back now. :-)  ]

Comment: You are missing an important cast in there.

Comment: @Justin `rand` returns an `int`. Assuming `n` is also an integer type and given that `RAND_MAX` is an integer, you are not going to get much randomness out of your method at all.

Comment: yep, I meant to get back to revise my too-vague and misleading note about casting to make it clearer that a type cast was needed if RAND_MAX * n > 0xFFFFFFFF, but I got busy and didn't make it back until now to update. thanks for keeping me on my toes!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a random variable which can take on values `{0, 1}` with `P(0) = P(1) = 0.5`. If you want to generate random values between `0` to `2` by summing two independent draws, you will have `P(0) = 0.25`, `P(1) = 0.5` and `P(2) = 0.25`.

Therefore, use an appropriate library unless you do not care at all about the PDF of the RNG.

See also Chapter 7 in [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php). (This is a link to the older edition but that's the one I studied anyway ;-)