# Will the difference between RAND_MAX and UINT_MAX vary?

Tags: c++, random, bit-manipulation

My homework involves making random integers between `0` and `2^30`. Now, in the past we've learned that `rand()` only returns integers up to `RAND_MAX`, that this is less than `UINT_MAX`, and that we can use bit shifting to fill up that `UINT_MAX` capacity. From some reading I've done (here, on SO), I realise that this may not be a very good idea if the distribution of these numbers matters to me. Having said that, my professor has specified this method.

My question is, by how much to bit shift? Will the difference between `RAND_MAX` and `UINT_MAX` always be such that there is a safe constant by which to bit shift? Or is there some initial probing that needs to be done to determine the number by which to bit shift? Should I just keep bit shifting by a little bit and checking against `UINT_MAX`?

The reason I ask is that, `UINT_MAX` is defined to be at least a certain number (`65535`), but on my machine `UINT_MAX` is much bigger (`4294967295`). This got me worried that I might finish my homework over the weekend, arrive at school, and find everything not working well enough to submit.

Thanks!

**References:**

I've read a couple of similar questions but couldn't garner an answer from them.

[Is the value of `RAND_MAX` always `(2^n)-1`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945698/is-the-value-of-rand-max-always-2n-1)

[generating a random number within range `0` to `n` where `n` can be `> RAND_MAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527108/generating-a-random-number-within-range-0-to-n-where-n-can-be-rand-max)

Actually, the second question above makes me question the worth of doing this at all?

Comment: out of curiosity, which school do you go to?

Comment: Langara College in Vancouver, BC (Canada). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question centers around whether `RAND_MAX` and `UINT_MAX` have a bit shift between them.  This reduces to the question of whether `UINT_MAX` and `RAND_MAX` are of the form `2^k - 1`. `UINT_MAX` almost assuredly would be on any binary number system-based computer. If `sizeof(int)=32` bits then `k=32`, if `sizeof(int)=64 bit` then `k=64`, etc. Now we can move to consider `RAND_MAX`. In most implementations the answer is that `RAND_MAX` will almost always be of the form `2^k - 1`. Why? We need to consider how most implementations of `rand()` actually work.

1. `rand()` typically uses a linear congruential generator (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator or Knuth "The Art of Computer Programmer Part 2 : Semi-Numerical Algorithms").  Basically a random number is a sequence with a `seed`

   x(k+1) = ( a x(k) + c ) % m

(i.e. the C library stores the last iterated `x(k)` and when you call `rand()` it returns `x(k+1)`)

1. To be of good quality, the parameters of the generator (`a`, `c`, and `m`) have to be chosen carefully.  Quality typically entails how many times before the sequence repeats itself, etc. One tension in the choice of these parameters is to make `m` as close to `UINT_MAX` as possible so as to not avoid wasting potential random bits. If you study the generators, typically the right choice is to make `m` somewhat smaller than `UINT_MAX`. You also need to make `m` a prime.
2. Typically you want `rand()` to be as fast as possible so you want these operations to be cheap.  The cheapest `mod` to compute is one of the form  `foo % (2^k - 1)` because it can be implemented as `foo & (1<<k-1)`.  For a special choice of `k` you will get a Mersenne prime.

For example,  A common choice is `k=31` which yields the prime `2^31-1 = 2147483647`. This is the typical choice for 32-bit integers where `UINT_MAX=2^32-1 = 4294967295`. For 64-bit numbers one has `UINT_MAX=2^64-1=18446744073709551615` and a choice for RAND_MAX would be `2^61-1 = 2305843009213693951`.

So in summary, to answer your question:  In most implementations you can assume there is a simple bit shift, however, there is no real guarantee.  At the very least you should do a run-time test at your program init. If you are using C++ a better practice would be to use a `static_assert` to detect at compile time whether your assumptions are true and fail to compile if they are not. Boost has such a static assert, as does the recently approved standard C++11... i.e. one can do (though it may take some work to write a static version of `is_power_of_two_minus_one`):

```
unsigned int myrand()
{
        static_assert(sizeof(int)==4,"sizeof(unsigned int) != 4");
        static_assert(is_power_of_two_minus_one(RAND_MAX),"RAND_MAX not a power of two minus one");
        static_assert(is_power_of_two_minus_one(UINT_MAX),"UINT_MAX not power of two minus one");
        unsigned int raw_rand=rand();
        // do your bit shift to adjust raw_rand
        return raw_rand;
}
```

Comment: Wow. I think that in a week you will have UINT_MAX reputation. This exactly answered all of my concerns, and if I could up-vote it 100 times I probably would. Thank you! Also: awesome resume!

Comment: How about `constexpr bool is_power_of_two_minus_one(unsigned long long n) { return ( n & (n+1) ) == 0; }`?

Answer (score 3):

> Actually, the second question above makes me question the worth of doing this at all?

If your professor told you to do it this way, you should do it this way.  It's not crypto-strength certainly, but for the purposes of a homework assignment it will be fine.

For `RAND_MAX` being `2^n - 1`, I'd generally assume so.  The way computers generate random numbers is a set number of bits at a time, so if the max weren't `2^n - 1`, either not all numbers in the range could be returned or entropy would be wasted.

As for the difference being the same on all systems, I'd strongly advise against assuming that.  In your code, figure out how many bits are in each and dynamically figure out how to shift.

And can't you ssh in to the school server you'll be (eventually) running this on?

Comment: Well, `rand` is never going to be cryptographically secure.